# How to not close the browser window in Protractor test?

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor, automated-tests

Protractor automation test is trying to open an angular website and enter username and password. Issue is the browser window closes even before the site is completely loaded. I was able to verify the title of the website and when the elements are loading the browser window closes . But in the console it says username and password is entered. What is that I am missing to run the tests?

I tried: 
1.Updating npm and windows-driver manager
2.Using Expected conditions and waiting until the login button is visible
3. Increasing wait time.

This is my config file:

```
  getPageTimeout: 60000,
  allScriptsTimeout: 60000,
  framework:'custom',
  frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),

  params: {
    website: {
      websiteURL: 'XXXXX',
      wait: 10000,
      username: 'username',
      password: 'password',

    },
```

This is my step definition:

````
  await browser.get(browser.params.website.websiteURL)
  browser.sleep(8000)

});

When('I enter username and password and click on login button', async () => {
  await (launcherPageObject.username).isDisplayed
  launcherPageObject.username.click
  launcherPageObject.username.sendKeys(browser.params.launcher.username)
  console.log("Username is entered")
  await (launcherPageObject.password).isDisplayed
  launcherPageObject.password.click
  launcherPageObject.password.sendKeys(browser.params.launcher.password)
  console.log("Password is entered")
  await(launcherPageObject.submitButton).isDisplayed
  launcherPageObject.submitButton.click
 });```

This is the console log:

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:57287/devtools/browser/28ca8fcd-1028-4539-8332-c7663d2dfd14
.Username is entered
Password is entered


Thanks
````

Answer (score 1):

you are missing js code.. first of all parenthesis for methods, and then you don't resolve promises with `await` keyword

```
 await browser.get(browser.params.website.websiteURL)
 await browser.sleep(8000) // <---------------

});

When('I enter username and password and click on login button', async () => {
  await (launcherPageObject.username).isDisplayed();  // <---------------
  await launcherPageObject.username.click();  // <---------------
  await launcherPageObject.username.sendKeys(browser.params.launcher.username)
  console.log("Username is entered")
```

etc